# Error when reading from pre-populated SQLite database in Ionic project

Tags: android, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm receiving an error when I try to read from a pre-populated SQLite database: `sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table 'plant'`

From what I understand SQLite looks for the mydb.db file in the /www folder by default, then creates an empty database when it doesn't find the pre-populated mydb.db file. This is why it can't find the 'plant' table, because the newly created blank database obviously doesn't contain a 'plant' table. However I can confirm that the database *is* in the /www folder, and that it contains the 'plant' table when I run `sqlite3 mydb.db` then `.tables` in the terminal.

I can't figure out why it's not reading from the pre-populated mydb.db file.

**Folder structure** (from root):

```
/src
-/app
--/app.component.ts
/www
-/mydb.db
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
  constructor(public platform: Platform, private sqlite: SQLite ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.getData();
    });
  }

  getData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'mydb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM plant ORDER BY id ASC', [])
      .then(res => {
        // Do Stuff
      }).catch(e => console.log("FAIL executeSql:", e));
    })
  }
```

I've attempted many fixes that I've found on StackOverflow, like wiping the app from my device, starting a new ionic project then copying app and config files over, and setting a direct path in the database location, but it still keeps trying to read from the empty database that it creates.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin *does not handle prepopulated databases* (as of this writing). I believe you need the **Cordova-sqlite-ext** plugin.

From the [README.md](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/storage-master/README.md) at the repo (emphasis mine):

> New release in September 2018 will include the following major enhancements (litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#773):
>
> - browser platform support using kripken / sql.js
>     (litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#576)
> - cordova-sqlite-storage and cordova-sqlite-ext plugin versions will be
>     combined, **no more separate plugin version needed for pre-populated
>     databases** ([litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#529](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/529))
> - include typings from DefinitelyTyped
>     (litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#768)

NB. The "**will**" include is the operative.

There is a similar question on the [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-prepopulated-sqlite-db/110423). The last post in the thread starts:

> Cordova SQLite Storage doesn’t use your app’s www folder to store
>   data.
>
> Mobile devices don’t allow for app executables’ data to be modified.
>   This is to prevent installing an app that overwrites code in another
>   app (imagine installing WhatsApp and it corrupts all other messaging
>   apps so you can’t use them). It also makes it impossible for code to
>   be injected into the app and take over the OS if your app security
>   isn’t great.

The post goes on with a proposed workaround.

Another [thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-and-cordova-sqlite-ext/92627) on the ionic forum seems to indicate that you can use **cordova-sqlite-ext** in your app. You could search that forum for `cordova-sqlite-ext`, there are several posters that have it working. There are also many results for `cordova-sqlite-ext` on this forum that could get you in the right direction.

And to be honest, I do not think it is actually creating an empty database. Unless "/www/mydb.db" is an empty database after you run the app (which would surprise me). While it's true that sqlite will create the database named at the command line if it doesn't exist, I suspect that in this case it is just the behaviour when it cannot access the named database.